# MVC Application to Display embedded PDF documents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have an MVC 4 Project that i publish to azure.  I Want to Embed PDF documents into some Pages.  I am looking for a Server side Solution that Does Not Depend on Client side Adobe Installation.  Has anyone found a good Solution for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html) that suggests embedding PDFs in HTML, typically via the PDF.JS library.